# Backbone events with Backbone DOM elements not firing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Events aren't firing and I'm not sure why.

This is how I initialize my view-

```
  tabModel1 = new TabModel()
  tabModel2 = new TabModel()
  tabs = new TabModels()
  tabsView = new Tabs({
    collection: tabs
  })
  tabs.add tabModel1
  tabs.add tabModel2
  $('body').append tabsView.$el
```

And this is my view code

```
class Tab extends Backbone.View
  className: 'tab'

  initialize: () ->
    @model.on('change','render')
    @render()

  render: () =>
    @$el.append("ChildTab")

  select:()->
    console.log 'child tab selected'

  events:
    '.tab' : 'select'


class Tabs extends Backbone.View
  className: 'tabs'

  initialize:()->
    @collection.on 'add',@_addTab
    @render()

  render:()->

  _addTab:(model)=>
    tabView = new Tab({
      model: model
    })
    @$el.append tabView.el

  _renderTab:(e)=>
    console.log "WHAT?"

  events:
    'click .tabs' : '_renderTab()'
```

Clicking on tabs or on tab is not firing the required click event.Why? I can confirm the elements are being appended.

Comment: You could try `'click .tabs' : '_renderTab'`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
class Tab extends Backbone.View
// ...
events:
  'click' : 'select'


class Tabs extends Backbone.View
// ...
events:
  'click' : '_renderTab'
```

Answer (score 0):

needed to do 'click' : 'func'

I think it was looking for a .tabs elem which was a child of .tabs.